# Haskell - How does this average function work?

Tags: haskell, average, applicative, function-composition, pointfree

I found this implementation of the average function:

```hs
avg :: [Int] -> Int
avg = div . sum <*> length
```

How does this work? I looked at the function that was produced as a result of `div . sum`:

```
(div . sum) :: (Integral a, Foldable t) => t a -> a -> a
```

I understand that, but I'm unable to tell how `<*> length` does the work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**`<*> :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) is the *sequential application* function that works on an [**`Applicative`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) structure. For a function, this is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-973):

> ```
> instance Applicative ((->) r) where
>     pure = const
>     (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
>     liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)
> ```

so `f <*> g` is short for `\x -> f x (g x)`. This thus means that in the case of `avg`:

```
avg = div . sum <*> length
```

is equivalent to:

```
avg x = (div . sum) x (length x)
```

which is thus equivalent to:

```
avg x = div (sum x) (length x)
```

so it divides the `sum x` with `length x`.

Comment: Piggybacking off this answer, one thing that has helped me with ab(uses) of `<*>` for functions is reading it like `div <$> sum <*> length`. If you're familiar with the `f <$> x <*> y <*> z ...` idiom, you can think of the function case as meaning "apply `x` to the first argument of `f`, `y` to the second, etc.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a fan of this particular pointfree-trick. It uses the `Applicative (a->)` instance as a “fanout”, to pass the argument to two separate functions. Essentially those two functions are `sum` and `length`, and the results are then combined back by `div`, which can be expressed nicely with arrow combinators (albeit a bit more verbose, because arrows don't really play in Haskell's default curried style):

```
import Control.Arrow

avg = uncurry div . (sum &&& length)
```

In the applicative trick, you merge the combining function into the first argument-sharing one. So `div . sum` in this case, and the *result* of the other function `length` is then passed into the second argument of the first function.

You can also use

```
avg = liftA2 div sum length
```

which uses the `Applicative` instance too.

Comment: Right! Actually I had it this way at first, but then on reading over the answer at the end somehow made a thought mistake that the whole thing still had two arguments.